# Retrieving values from an ArrayList of IntArrays

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, reference

So I know I'm missing something obvious, however, after searching similar/related questions, I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

New to Kotlin, so probably something I'm not understanding properly.

Creating an ArrayList, as I need a growing list of items, starting with none. Think of it like an undo list.  It'll grow to an unknown size. At some point, I'll reset it back to "empty" when needed.

Inside this list, I need an Array of Integers. These 3 values are a co-ordinate system - if it matters (ie x,y,z).

Everything I try, I keep ending up only being able to retrieve the final IntArray set added.

Using:
https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground

```
fun main() {
    // array list
    var myList = arrayListOf<IntArray>()
    // 3 item "test" array to populate array list with
    var myArr = IntArray(3){0}
    
    // setup Array list with 3 items
    for ( b in 0..2 ) {
        // fake/create a temp array with some simple values
        for ( i in 0..2 ) { myArr[i] = 3+b+(3*i) }
        
        // add it to the List
        myList.add(b, myArr)
        // confirm values
        println ( "Added [" + myList.lastIndex +"] = " + myArr[0] +"-"+ myArr[1] +"-"+ myArr[2] )
    }
    // confirm size of Array List
    println ( "size: " + myList.size )

    // test pull the middle array from the ArrayList
    // indices should be: 0, 1 and 2
    var testArr = myList.get(1)
    println ( "for idx 1: vals: " + testArr[0] +"-"+ testArr[1] +"-"+ testArr[2])
    
    // test display all values for all arrays
    myList.forEach {
        println ( "Vals: " + it[0] +"-"+ it[1] +"-"+ it[2] )
    }
    // another method to do same ?
    for ((index,value) in myList.withIndex()) {
        println("index: $index ... " + value[0] +"-"+ value[1] +"-"+ value[2])
    }
}
```

output is:

```
Added [0] = 3-6-9
Added [1] = 4-7-10
Added [2] = 5-8-11
size: 3
for idx 1: vals: 5-8-11
Vals: 5-8-11
Vals: 5-8-11
Vals: 5-8-11
index: 0 ... 5-8-11
index: 1 ... 5-8-11
index: 2 ... 5-8-11
```

Everything makes perfect sense up until the repeats of "5-8-11" .. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in:

`for ( i in 0..2 ) { myArr[i] = 3+b+(3*i) }`

you always modifying and adding the same object: `myArr` .

To fix, replace

`for ( i in 0..2 ) { myArr[i] = 3+b+(3*i) }`

with

`val a = IntArray(3) { i -> 3+b+(3*i) }`

and then add `a`:

`myList.add(a)`

Or, if populating the IntArray is as simple as in the example just:

`myList.add(IntArray(3) { i -> 3+b+(3*i) })`

The final code looks like this:

```
fun main() {
    val myList = arrayListOf<IntArray>()

    // setup Array list with 3 items
    for ( b in 0..2 ) {
        myList.add(IntArray(3) { i -> 3+b+(3*i) })
    }
    for ((index,value) in myList.withIndex()) {
        println("index: $index ... " + value[0] +"-"+ value[1] +"-"+ value[2])
    }
}
```

or even more concise (probably too much):

```
fun main() {
    val myList = List(3) { b -> IntArray(3) { i -> 3 + b + (3 * i) } }

    for ((index, value) in myList.withIndex()) {
        println("index: $index ... " + value[0] + "-" + value[1] + "-" + value[2])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. so wait .. I can't change the values in an array by just:  myArr[i] = (newvalue)??
and what's the significance of it being an "object" ?  I'll be honest, I don't believe I need an object, nor was I trying for one .. just wanted a "simple" IntArray ... that I can assign values to .. and reassign/change values to later .. ??

Comment: I also can't seem to understand what you're saying, when the output is showing the values of the array here:  "Added [0] = 3-6-9
Added [1] = 4-7-10
Added [2] = 5-8-11"  the array IS being updated .. is the add() function on the arraylist not correct?  (ie give new index "b", array/object/whatever "myArr") .. if I confirmed that myArr has new/proper values .. why are those values not making it into the arraylist?

Comment: @Ditto, what languages are you coming from? An array in Kotlin is an object, and not like a C struct. If you only called the IntArray constructor one time like you did, you only have one instance of the same array. You put the same IntArray instance into your list 3 times. You have not created multiple copies of it.

Comment: You can totally change values in an array, in fact you are over writing them every time. Your code bulds up a list of three references / pointers to the very same array.

Comment: @Tenfour04: ahhh .. so it's not copying, but instead putting a reference to it?  ie "pass by reference" kinda logic, vs "pass by value"?   If so, that starts making sense now ;)

Comment: ok .. yep, I understand now, thanks!   I added this line to end of my test script: "myArr[1] = 444"  then re-ran the "myList.forEach" block to show the values .. and output is "Vals: 5-444-11
Vals: 5-444-11
Vals: 5-444-11"   so right .. myList doesn't have a copy of the VALUES of the array, but just a pointer/reference to the array .. and when I update it .. hmm.   
Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I read your code, I think the problem is the IntArray you use, it is an object, every time you add it to the list, it is the same object. so In the end, it is always the same element.
please change the code to the following:

```
...
for ( b in 0..2 ) {
        // fake/create a temp array with some simple values
        var myArr = IntArray(3){0}
        for ( i in 0..2 ) { myArr[i] = 3+b+(3*i) }
        
        // add it to the List
        myList.add(b, myArr)
        // confirm values
        println ( "Added [" + myList.lastIndex +"] = " + myArr[0] +"-"+ myArr[1] +"-"+ myArr[2] )
    }
...
```

that should resolve your problem.

Here is the explanation of the reference object

> As you work with objects, it's important to understand references.
> A reference is an address that indicates where an object's variables and methods are stored.
> You aren't using objects when you assign an object to a variable or pass an object to a method as an argument. You aren't even using copies of the objects. Instead, you're using references to those objects.

Here is the [description about kotlin](https://www.ictdemy.com/kotlin/oop/reference-data-types-in-kotlin), it explains by image and content, you can read this.

Comment: The explanation is formatted as quote. What is the source?

Comment: @KarstenGabriel, I update the answer, you can see it.

Answer (score -1):

> Creating an ArrayList, as I need a growing list of items, starting
> with none. Think of it like an undo list. It'll grow to an unknown
> size. At some point, I'll reset it back to "empty" when needed.

This sounds like you need a Stack. You could use a MutableList for this, or the [ArrayDeque](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/) class. With *size, addLast(element), clear, contains(element), isEmpty(), last() , and removeLast()* you have everything at hand for manipulating something like an Undo list.

To construct it you would do:

```
val stack = ArrayDeque<IntArray>()
for (b in 0..2) {
  val intArray = IntArray(3)
  for (i in 0..2) {
    intArray[i] = 3 + b + (3 * i)
  }
  stack.addLast(intArray)
}

stack.forEach { println(it.joinToString("-")) }
```

Output:

```
3-6-9
4-7-10
5-8-11
```

Comment: I think it is not the collection type problem

Comment: I didn't say it was. You pointed out the error in the OPs code, and I just added an alternative approach.

Comment: OK, it is good to point out it in your answer